# What are the names of the three main parts of my metal spatula?

Tags: equipment

What are the names of the three main parts of my metal spatula?

1. Handle
2. Flat part that comes in contact with the food
3. The connecting metal which has rivets or pins attaching it to 1 and 2

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there are any 'official' names, but I suggest:

1. Handle
2. Blade
3. Shaft